# Is there a way to download a Docker image without Docker daemon?

Tags: docker, docker-registry, dockerhub

There is [docker-rust-musl image that takes around 2.5 hours to build from scratch](https://github.com/andrew-d/docker-rust-musl/pull/3#issuecomment-174385658) (on a single-core machine, which is allocated for Docker Hub Automated Builds), but the time limit for Docker Hub Automated builds is 2 hours.

I'm contemplating a way to split the long-running build into stages, so each stage would fit Docker Hub time limits. However, simply inherited images will result in a huge image, so I thought of creating an image which would pull the last stage and would copy only necessary stuff, thus making the final image clean and slim.

I have found [docker-registry-debug](https://github.com/samalba/docker-registry-debug) project, but it targets legacy Docker Registry (instead of new Distribution).

Comment: Do you really have to use Dockerhub? Because quay.io offers Squashed-Image-Download-Links!

Comment: Hmm, great point! We will investigate this way.